# Hyperledger Composer's Future

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I recently learned Hyperledger Composer. So, I wanted to know if Composer is actively being developed or is it going to be obsoleted in the near future.

I tried looking over the internet but could not get the right information.

Thanks

Comment: see https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/composer/message/125 for an answer

Comment: @david_k it looks like the composer is not much really in future IBM plans unless something they found it to keep alive.

Comment: I would recommend looking at the new programming models in hyperledger fabric, these programming models come from the creators of composer

Comment: @david_k, are you talking about below link: https://wiki.hyperledger.org/display/fabric/Fabric+Developer%3A+New+Programming+Model+resources ?

Comment: The programming models for node are covered throughout the documentation of fabric. Also check out their reference doc sites of https://fabric-shim.github.io (contract api) and https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io (fabric-network). The node and typescript samples will in fabric-samples will also use these programming models (referred to as the high level api)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question we can answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, nobody is working on Hyperledger Composer. The IBM resources have been redirected to Hyperledger Fabric around November 2018. The problem was Fabric was evolving and Composer only presented a subset of Fabric's capabilities.

That said, it is open source. Anyone can pick it up and start working on it. But I doubt that will happen.

Comment: got it, Dan. It looks to me that in some later versions of Fabric itself we could see composer like stuff.